# Craft 3 redirecting me 404 after fill up registration form

Tags: craft3, registration

I have created copy whole HTML from here (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-registration-form.html). and trying to register but it's showing me an error or we can say it redirects me to 404 error.

URL: lawbros.uldev.co/users/registration.html

Answer (score 1):

I had made a small mistake to add action in the form tag. its 'users/saveUser' needs to be updated to 'users/save-user'.